# Outlook - Create a custom button to open up a Pane when New meeting is being created

Tags: reactjs, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a requirement to create a task pane when a New Meeting button in outlook is clicked with React Js.

I am new to the Outlook add-in development.

So any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Outlook web add-ins work under the currently selected item in Outlook. If you need to create a custom ribbon button which opens a task pane - that is a supported scenario. Read more about that in the [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) article.

Comment: This is the correct answer - We support opening the task pane when the add-in ribbon button is clicked